# Fill days between dates with certain conditions in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have this dataframe:

```
d = {'Region':['And','And'],
'country': ['ES','ES'],
'Date': [01/01/2016,01/01/2017,],
'holiday': [1,1]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I would like to add to the dataframe rows for all dates between those two, with a 0 in holiday and the same region and country as the extremes. I would need to do that for several countries, regions and date gaps of different length.

Comment: Where is your non-working attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems in your code - you haven't closed the dictionary, and your dates need to be enclosed as strings. Python won't automatically recognise them as datetime objects.

Here is a fixed version of what you have:

```
d = {'Region':['And','And'],
'country': ['ES','ES'],
'Date': ['01/01/2016','01/01/2017',],
'holiday': [1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

The best way to do what you want to do is, after adding date as a datetime object, set the date range (including the in-between values - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python) how to do that) as an index in a separate dataframe, which will add the remaining values as NaN. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30564745)